# Cross compile PHP for aarch64 - error can not run test

Tags: php, linux, gcc, compilation

I'm trying to compile PHP 7.0.1  (downloaded on PHP website) for aarch64 platform.(aarch64 GNU/Linux)

I configure for compile like this :

```
export ARCH=arm64
export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
export PATH=$PATH:/home/xyz/gcc-linaro-aarch64-linux-gnu-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin

./configure  --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/xyz --disable-libxml --disable-dom --without-iconv --without-openssl --disable-simplexml --disable-xml --disable-xmlreader --disable-xmlwriter --without-pear --without-sqlite3 --disable-pdo --without-pdo-sqlite --disable-phar --disable-test


 checking for strcasestr... configure: error: in /home/xyz/PHP/php-7.0.1: 
  configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling 
  See config.log for more details
```

Ask me if you need more precision.

Answer (score -2):

At the end of the `./configure` line replace the `--disable-test` with `--disable-all` and it will work.